# Salesforce mobile push notification for react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to integrate salesforce SDK for mobile push notification in react native using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-marketingcloudsdk I am running the application on android real device. However application crash without any error log. Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import RegisterComponent from './RegistrationComponent';
import LogginComponent from './LoggingComponent';
import MCReactModule from 'react-native-marketingcloudsdk';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    alert('contactKey')
    let contactKey = await MCReactModule.getContactKey();
    alert(contactKey)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', padding: 8}}>
          <Text>working</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi @Vicky Keshri, I am currently implementing the same salesforce rn library in my application, I am able to get push notification in app.js for iOS with notifee library, but's not for Android, can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't help in this issue . But you can use [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) for push notification .

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for salesforce SDK integration.